# How to secure a XML file in Windows Phone 7

Tags: xml, security, windows-phone-7, encryption, cryptography

I want to add an XML file, containing sensitive data, to my application.

I don't want anyone to be able to get this file and use its content.

How can I achieve this?

I thought using encryption might be a good idea, but then how can I pass the encryption password without writing it in the code ? (I don't want somebody to be able to find it by using a decompiler)

Is Isolated Storage considered a safe place? Can somebody else, other than my application, reach it?

Comment: Have you considered storing it on a server and accessing it via a web service, which requires credentials from your application?

Comment: This is what I am currently using, but users are complaining of poor performances because network connectivity is often slow on phone.

Comment: I also was trying to solve this problem, but ended up with nothing. 
Obfuscation can help a little, but does not prevent someone highly motivated to get the data. So when the data in XAP and somebody has this XAP, you can do almost nothing. But I will be really happy to see if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - there is no 100% secure method to store your XML file on the phone, as it can be extracted from the Isolated Storage regardless of whether you allow it or now. Your best bet is encrypting the file and obfuscating the source-code.

> Have the encryption key specified by the user, instead of having it
>   **hard-coded**.

[Dave Amenta suggested](https://twitter.com/#!/davux/status/187959498055487488) using [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which might be *one of the ways* you might want to approach this problem.

Comment: The only real answer here should be to use ProtectedData.. using encryption is pointless when you have to store the key. Even when it's obfuscated, it's still easy to use Reflector / dotPeek.

Comment: That is why you don't store the key and ask the user to enter it every time the sensitive data is accessed.

Comment: True... Although it's seems obvious what method would be easier and have a better UX :)

Comment: Indeed. It just depends on how *really sensitive* the data is.